# npm install return: mongodb is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I'm beginner in nodeJs I want to install the environment  to make login page with mongodb,
I create this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "loginapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "simple app",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "test test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies":{
    "bcryptjs":"*",
    "body-parser":"*",
    "connect-flash":"*",
    "cookie-parser":"^1.4.1",
    "express":"*",
    "express-handlebars":"*",
    "express-messages":"*",
    "express-session":"*",
    "express-validator":"*",
    "mongobd":"*",
    "mongoose":"*",
    "passport":"*",
    "passport-http":"*",
    "passport-local":"*"
  }
}
```

and when I wanted to install with npm install I found this error :
[img-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeIKg.png)

thank's for helping ..

Comment: `"mongobd"` is not **`"mongodb"`**. I think you are about to learn the lesson not to post and then "run away" on StackOverflow. I don't see this being received well.

Comment: TYPO: `"mongobd":"*"` -> `"mongodb":"*"`

Comment: you are right I did not see it